# Function reconstruction after a DWT

Tags: wavelet, reconstruction, discrete-wavelet-transform, pywavelets

I'm new to this field, my apologies if my question sounds too naive.

From what I understood, a function can be decomposed using the scaling function at a given scale $\{\phi_{J, k}\}_{k \in \mathbb{Z}}$ and the wavelets at finer scales $\{\psi_{j,k}\}_{j \le J, k \in \mathbb{Z}}$.
So given a discrete signal that represents the sampling of a function $f$, one could use its wavelet decomposition to reconstruct a continuous approximation of the function $f \approx \sum\limits_{k \in \mathbb{Z}}a_{J, k} \phi_{J, k} + \sum\limits_{k \in \mathbb{Z}} \sum\limits_{j = J}^L d_{j, k} \psi_{j,k} $, up to a resolution $L$ determined by the sampling density.

I tried to do that in Python using `pywt`, using my code below.
However, when I reconstruct, I have to use two 'adjustment' variables $A$ and $B$ to align the reconstructed signal to the original one.

I understand that the constant shift $B$ comes from the fact we only get a finite sequence of coefficients that has to be shifted, but the constant $A$ that I have adjusted manually does not make sense to me.

Did I do something wrong, or is there a point I didn't get?
Thanks for your help!

````
import numpy as np
from math import sqrt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pywt


def test_func(x):
    k1 = 5
    k2 = 20
    k = k1 + (k2 - k1) * (4 * (x-0.5)**3 + 0.5)
    return np.sin(k * x)
    
def sample_signal(test_f, scale):
    dx = pow(2, -scale)
    x = np.arange(0, 1, dx)
    y = np.array([test_f(x[i]) for i in range(x.shape[0])])
    y = test_f(x)
    return x, y
    
    
if __name__ == '__main__':

    # Generate discrete signal
    scale = 7
    x, y = sample_signal(test_func, scale)
    
    # Wavelet decomposition
    wavelet = pywt.Wavelet('db2')
    coeffs = pywt.wavedec(y, wavelet)
    nb_levels = len(coeffs) - 1
    
    # Upsample wavelet function + linear interpolation
    phi_dis, psi_dis, x_wav_dis = wavelet.wavefun(level=scale+2)
    def find_x_inter(x):
        # Dichotomic search of the interval
        ix_min = 0
        ix_max = len(x_wav_dis) - 1
        ix = int((ix_min + ix_max) / 2)
        if x < x_wav_dis[ix_min] or x > x_wav_dis[ix_max]:
            return 0, -1.
        while not (x_wav_dis[ix] <= x and x <= x_wav_dis[ix + 1]):
            if x_wav_dis[ix] > x:
                ix_max = ix
            else:
                ix_min = ix
            ix = int((ix_min + ix_max) / 2)
        alpha = (x - x_wav_dis[ix]) / (x_wav_dis[ix + 1] - x_wav_dis[ix])
        return ix, alpha
    def phi(x):
        ix, alpha = find_x_inter(x)
        if alpha < 0:
            return 0.
        return (1. - alpha) * phi_dis[ix] + alpha * phi_dis[ix + 1]
    def psi(x):
        ix, alpha = find_x_inter(x)
        if alpha < 0:
            return 0.
        return (1. - alpha) * psi_dis[ix] + alpha * psi_dis[ix + 1]
            
    # Reconstruct
    k_s = 1. / sqrt(pow(2, scale))
    #dx = 4.e-3
    x_rec = x #np.arange(0, 1, dx)
    y_rec = []
    # Fixing parameters
    A = 0.0105              # <<<<<<<<<<<< db2: ~0.0105
    B = wavelet.rec_len - 2 # <<<<<<<<<<<<
    for i in range(x_rec.shape[0]):
        xi = x_rec[i] - A #pow(2, -scale)
        val = 0.
        # Approx
        c_a = coeffs[0]
        inv_s = pow(2, scale - nb_levels) 
        inv_sqrt_s = sqrt(inv_s) 
        for k in range(c_a.shape[0]):
            val += k_s * inv_sqrt_s * c_a[k] * phi(inv_s * xi - k + B)
        # Details
        for j in range(nb_levels):
            c_d = coeffs[j + 1]
            inv_s = pow(2, scale + j - nb_levels)
            inv_sqrt_s = sqrt(inv_s)
            for k in range(c_d.shape[0]):
                val += k_s * inv_sqrt_s * c_d[k] * psi(inv_s * xi - k + B)
        y_rec.append(val)
    y_rec = np.array(y_rec)
    
    
    # Plot
    plt.plot(x, y, label='Initial')
    plt.plot(x_rec, y_rec, label='Reconstructed')
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()     
```
````